# How Can I found the process id of a console app in debug from visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kill, taskmanager

I got a Visual Studio solution with a console project inside. When running in debug the console application it seems to run till it ends. But apparently, the corresponding *.exe is still in use, since it cannot be manually deleted from the bin folder. Not even after closing the Visual Studio.

The Console Application has a human-readable name like MyApplication.blabla.exe, but I cannot find it in the task manager.

Is there any way to find the id of that process so that I can do a kill of the process?  or any way to identify which of the elements in the task manager is the one that actually is running MyApplication.blabla.exe?

Comment: Resource Monitor > CPU > Associated Handles, try to search the file name.

Comment: This is an anti-malware problem.  Don't use the aggressive stuff on a programmer's machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you can run this solution using Visual Studio:

Debug => Attach to Process

Then you need to search for the name of the exe on the opened page, as shown below:

[image]

Here you can see the Process ID of the exe